# How not to use loop in a df when access previous lines

Tags: python, pandas

I use pandas to process transport data. I study attendance of bus lines. I have 2 columns to count people getting on and off the bus at each stop of the bus. I want to create one which count the people currently on board. At the moment, i use a loop through the df and for the line n, it does : current[n]=on[n]-off[n]+current[n-1] as showns in the following example:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
if index == 0:
    df.loc[index,'current']=df.loc[index,'on']
else :
    df.loc[index,'current']=df.loc[index,'on']-df.loc[index,'off']+df.loc[index-1,'current']
```

Is there a way to avoid using a loop ?

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Series.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), which accumulates the the numbers in a given Series.

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[3,4],[6,4],[1,2],[4,5]], columns=["off", "on"])
a["current"] = a["on"].cumsum() - a["off"].cumsum()

   off  on  current
0    3   4        1
1    6   4       -1
2    1   2        0
3    4   5        1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the problem properly, you could calculate the difference between people getting on and off, then have a running total using [`Series.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
import pandas as pd
# Create dataframe for demo
d = {'Stop':['A','B','C','D'],'On':[3,2,3,2],'Off':[2,1,0,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Get difference between 'On' and 'Off' columns.
df['current'] = df['On']-df['Off']

# Get cumulative sum of column
df['Total'] = df['current'].cumsum()



# Same thing in one line
df['Total'] = (df['On']-df['Off']).cumsum()


Stop    On    Off    Total
 A      3      2       1
 B      2      1       2
 C      3      0       5
 D      2      1       6
```